# How to favourite Tweet using Twitter API

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am using Abrahm library https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

I can able to post and retweet but try this code for favorite

```
$fav_tweets=$connection->post("favorites/create/id=835432351400357888");
```

or

```
$fav_tweets=$connection->post("favorites/create.json?id=835432351400357888");
```

or

```
$fav_tweets=$connection->post("favorites/create/835432351400357888");
```

But no code works, they return the result:

```
stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 32 [message] => Could not authenticate you. ) ) )
```

Please help guys
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example shown at https://twitteroauth.com/, try:

```
$statues = $connection->post("favorites/create", ["id" => "835432351400357888"]);
```